# Logging error while doing a ajax post request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax call from cstml page:

```
function InvoiceableItems(data) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: apiRoot + 'createOrUpdate',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "json"
            });
        }
```

Api Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult CreateOrUpdate(QuotationItemInvoiceableItemsSavingDto[] data)
{
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Error in console in firefox:

> The requested resource does not support http method
>   'GET'.

The error also throws when we go to network in chrome and click on the api call request.

Comment: in View source of the call also we can see:-view-source:https:..................../.../.../createOrUpdate

Comment: If you look at the request in Chrome, do you see it sending a GET or POST?  It's possible that a redirect is happening to a different url or your routing isn't setup correctly to hit that action endpoint.  What happens if you remove [HttpPost]?  Does the action get triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing bracket on InvoiceableItems(data)? Or has apiRoot definitely been defined?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var apiRoot = "http://<myurlbase>";

    function InvoiceableItems(data) { 
        return $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            url: apiRoot + 'createOrUpdate', 
            data: JSON.stringify(data), 
            contentType: 'application/json', 
            dataType: "json" }); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Presumably jQuery has already been defined before this gets called?

You can use fiddler to test that your method works as expected, setting the method as post. If you put a url into chrome, firefox, etc. it will default as get causing the error you saw.

Comment: Actually the method works as expected and it makes a call even if from fiddler. But it Logs some in the console and when we open the error it says in viewsource The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

Comment: I am not exactly able to figure out the cause of the issue

Comment: Is your api on a different host / port? If so CORS configured correctly - has the POST verb been set as allowed? See [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods)